# Trying to disable browser alert; setting window.onbeforeload to null not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working within a jquery POST request that posts some form data. After the POST is successful, I want to set the window.onbeforeunload = null before reloading the page. I do this because I do NOT want the javascript popup saying "Do you want to reload this page? Changes will not be saved." to show up.

```
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/report.json',
            data: formData,
            success: function(response) {
                doSomething(response);
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
                window.location.reload();
            }
```

I have tried a couple of other implementations of the window.onbeforeunload. I have tried it this way...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return null;
}
```

and this way...

```
$(window).on(beforeunload, function() {
    return null;
}
```

All I am looking to do is to reload the page without the javascript popup showing up. I am having this issue in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This is not very clear, but unless you've already set `window.onbeforeunload` to something, it shouldn't show an alert on reload or redirect. One does however wonder why you use ajax to submit a form, and then just reloads the page, which is what a native form submit does without any javascript at all?

Comment: Walking through the breakpoints in my application, the window.onbeforeunload is executed right after location.reload() is called. I know this to be true as in a previous implementation I tried, I had the following setup:

`window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return null; //breakpoint
};
window.location.reload();`

Comment: To address the reason as to why I am not using a form... It is not actually a "form" at the moment. I can make that change and see if using onsubmit (or something along those lines) would work. At the moment, it is just a button with an onclick.

Comment: Also, I do believe that because I am redefining the window.onbeforeunload behavior, any other instances of onbeforeunload would not take effect.

Comment: Scratch that. Elsewhere on this page, a `$(window).bind('beforeunload', ...` was executing as well. I made some changes to what is happening there and it seems to be working. Thanks for the inspiration!